# erc20 token stop trading after minting tokens

Tags: erc-20

hi i need help im the contact owner i did mint tokens but after i made mistake and trading stoped on uniswap can any one help me out will be rewarded big
@carlosnond is my telegram or email megazino1@gmail.com
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: What is the token or transaction that failed? Without any detail is really hard to say anything concrete.

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x8da25b8ed753a5910013167945a676921e864436#code this is the contract adres they say something is wrong with staking that is paused training . so question is can empty liq or start resume trading  and this is the uniswap link https://info.uniswap.org/pair/0x6c25cf2160db4a1be0f1317fc301f5a5cdba9199

Comment: After examining for a few minutes the contract is broken. The owner has enabling the staking with a wrong contract so transfer stopped working. Later they renounced to the ownership making impossible for anyone to fix the contract. Looking around social media the team appears to unresponsive since November 9. It appears to be a rug pull.